# display whole localStorage of browser on webpage

Tags: javascript, browser

im just asking myself is it possible with a simple javascript to read the whole localStorage of all Websites in your browser and display it on a html page? Is there any way to do this? I haven't found anything on Google only ways to extract one stored key.

Comment: You can not read all the contents for every domain from one webpage. That is a security nightmare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the current domain use something like:

```
for (var key in localStorage){
   console.log(key + ': ' + localStorage.getItem( key ))
}
```

Ofcourse you can put the values in an array or display them in any other way.

( Example code will display key/values in your console.. ctrl+J in google chrome and click console, or F12 in windows and click console )

However: Javascript is not able to access the local storage for other domains then the current one. Because if could, it would also allow malicious website owners to ie. read that data and submit it with ajax to their sites.

**EDIT**:
In google chrome you can hit CTRL-J and then go to the Resources tab. It will contain a Local Storage item in the tree and a child for each domain that has a local storage on your system. You can view the contents there.

Answer (score 0):

No! It's only possible to access the local storage of the domain in which you reside. It's a security feature.

Answer (score 0):

Local- and sessionStorage have to obey the SOP (Same Origin Policy), much like an Ajax request.

To do it on the same domain you can just iterate through it since local- and sessionStorage are both JavaScript Objects.

```
for(var i in localStorage)
{
    var item = localStorage.getKey(i);
    console.log(i + " => " + item);
}
```